# LINQ to delete UIElement in SilverLight Children

Tags: .net, linq, silverlight-3.0, uielement

```
foreach (UIElement el in GridBoard.Children.ToList())
{
   if (el is Ellipse)
   {
       GridBoard.Children.Remove(el);
   }
}
```

Is there any LINQ equivalent to do the above? If yes, can please provide the code?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is used to query collections rather than cause side-effects. According to MSDN Silverlight doesn't support `List<T>`'s `RemoveAll` method but does support the `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods, otherwise you would've been able to write: `GridBoard.Children.ToList().RemoveAll(el => el is Ellipse);`

You could use LINQ as follows:

```
var query = GridBoard.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList();
foreach (var e in query)
{
    GridBoard.Children.Remove(e);
}
```

Alternately, you could traverse your list in reverse and use `RemoveAt` which would yield some better performance then using `Remove`:

```
for (int i = GridBoard.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (GridBoard.Children[i] is Ellipse)
        GridBoard.Children.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

So it's not much different than what you had. Perhaps `RemoveAll` support will make it's way into future Silverlight versions and it would be the best choice.